# Update panel in asp.net

Tags: updatepanel

I am using two update panel..in nested way.. can i use like this and also
in my project im using clientscript.RegisterScript along with update panel , its not giving any error but , my pop up is not being displayed when i click one item on grid. the pop up is in update panel which is inside (nested).. 
can anyone help ???

Thank you

Comment: Can you give more details and post some *relevant* code samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RegisterScript` may not work well with updatepanel. use `PageRequestManager.add_endRequest` method to hook-up client script in this scenario.

```
        if (window.Sys){            
            var prmx = window.Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prmx.add_endRequest(function() {
                alert('insert your code here...');
            });
        }
```

also make sure there is no javascript erros during page load.